# How can I set up a build server that accepts git pushes (Heroku style)?

Tags: ssh, git, heroku

A lot of services designed for running lightweight apps on clusters (Flynn, Deis, Dokku) are following Heroku's deployment standard of adding a git remote and pushing to it when you want to build and/or deploy an application. The build output is sent back to the user who sent the git push, right in their tty.

How can I set up my own server with git and ssh to do actions on push and relay information back to the user?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). You can have a git hook on the server that is executed when code is pushed to it. My guess is that any output you do in these hooks is relayed to the client per default (not 100% sure though).